# Merging polygons based on attribute values

Tags: qgis, merge, features

I have a large feature dataset with thousands of entries. Each entry is represented by a polygon. The most have unique values in all fields but some of them have to be merged based on a identity number in a field (zip code). I want to merge these polygons without losing the other field values. Is there a operation for this in QGIS?

here is a a screenshot of the aggregate function:
[image: aggregate function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate` for this. See the documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate

To keep all attribute values, you can concatenate them. This works well for string (text) fields. If you have integers, you must convert them to string using `to_string("attribute")` (replace `attribute` with the name of the respective attribute). Don't forget to set the resulting field-type to text and define a field-length long enough to include all values:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I will check this tomorrow morning and post a update.

Comment: I could need some help getting this to work. What function of aggregate would be the way to go to keep all the field values. There is a bunch (sum, concencate collect,...) of them and I am not very into these functions.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your attribute table (or provide sample data)?

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of the aggregate function. I'd like to keep all the field values from field r to field s. There seems to be a command concatenate for string, but I could not find a smiliar function for integer. Is there one?

Comment: What you added is the aggregate dialog window, not the attribute table. Never mind: see updated answer.

Comment: There is one last question i have: The aggregation takes hours and hours. About 2% an hour. It's a big dataset I'm trying to porcess. Is there a chance to speed this up? Or is there a similiar way to get do this aggragation in ArcMap(I have the felling, that Arc Map is sometimes a bit faster in processing)?

Comment: Processing speed of course depends on the size of your data. Without having any idea about how your data looks, I can't say anything about this. Further, I don't have any experience with ArcMap. You should ask a separate question for this - the policy of this site is to have separate questions for each task and each software.

Comment: You might split your layer into those with duplicates and those without and then apply the aggregation on only the duplicates.  Then merge the two sets back together.  This expression will get the duplicates:  Count(1,"ID")>1 replacing ID with your zip code field